# SPRING: Using Autowiring inside a bean created by factory instantaion in spring

Tags: spring

Hi I am unable to autowire my bean inside another bean which is instantiated using a factory method.

```
class A{

    private String name;

    //getters and setters for name
}

class B{

    @Autowired
    private A x;

    private B(String Gender, String jobProfile){
        String name = x.getName();
       //some code
    }

    public static getInstance(String Gender,String jobProfile){
        //some code for instantiation.
    }
}
```

Now when i create the instance of class B using factory method, from some different class. Autowiring does not happens, it returns NULL i.e. x is coming as null. Hence i am getting null pointer exceptions when calling getName on this

Have you any solution for it ?? or i am doing somethign wroing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an object by new, autowire\inject don't work...

as workaround you can try this:

and create an istance in this way

```
context.getBean("myBean");
```

**PROTOTYPE** : This scopes a single bean definition to have any number of object instances.

---

Config

```
<bean id="a" class="..." >
<bean id="b" class="..." scope="prototype">
<bean id="factory" class="..." >
```

Factory class

```
public class Factory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public B createClass(){
        context.getBean("b");
    }

    public B createClass(Object... args){
        context.getBean("b",args);
    }

    }
```

in this way Autowired annotation works fine.

As Javadocs say getBean ..

```
/**
     * Return an instance, which may be shared or independent, of the specified bean.
     * <p>Allows for specifying explicit constructor arguments / factory method arguments,
     * overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the bean definition.
     * @param name the name of the bean to retrieve
     * @param args arguments to use if creating a prototype using explicit arguments to a
     * static factory method. It is invalid to use a non-null args value in any other case.
     * @return an instance of the bean
     * @throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException if there is no such bean definition
     * @throws BeanDefinitionStoreException if arguments have been given but
     * the affected bean isn't a prototype
     * @throws BeansException if the bean could not be created
     * @since 2.5
     */
    Object getBean(String name, Object... args) throws BeansException;
```

Comment: i created my bean using getBean only
Object[] argument = new Object[2];
        argument[0] = "F";
        argument[1] = "AGM";
        return (B) this.applicationContext.getBean("B", argument);

Comment: Can you add the full code? .. add information on your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the [@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) documentation is said that fields are autowired after object construction.

So in your code Spring has not jet injected `x` when you try to use `x.getName()` in constructor.

---

You have several options:

- move A x into the constructor
- move initialization logic out of the constructor

Comment: How can I move initialization logic out of the constructor. Whereto?