# Autowiring null in the second request

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have annotated my spring classes , however whenever I fire the webservice for the second time I get the null exception. For the first time it works fine.

I have Autowired the dao classes.

```
@Component
public class JdbcUserDAO implements UserDAO {

@Component
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(User.class);
    //private JdbcUserDAO jdbcUserDao = new JdbcUserDAO();
    @Autowired
    JdbcUserDAO jdbcUserDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editprofile", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Response<User> editProfile(@RequestBody User userIn) {       
        Response<User> response = new Response<User>();
        user =  user.edit(userIn);
```

Comment: Some code samples would be helpful.

Comment: @DanielOlszewski : Added it here

Comment: I think that you have a `new User` somewhere. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25991352/3364187)

Comment: @Xstian : I removed it still the problem persists

Comment: Can you show us your `web.xml`?

Comment: @Xstian : It's spring boot , there is no web.xml

Comment: @Xstian: It is like service call is successful in the first event but dao object becomes null for the same request.

Comment: Have you tried to change `@Component` in `@Controller` above `User` class? If you are sure to avoid `new` operation, could be that.

Comment: @Xstian: I will try doing that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96966/discussion-between-chetan-and-xstian).